# Python text parser for C++ program?

Tags: python, c++, windows

Anyone that has tried text parsing in C++ compared to Python will notice a considerable difference in effort and difficulty with Python being the easier of the two quite normally. For this reason I would much rather write a text parsing function in Python that my program written in C++ can use.

I thought of compiling a `.py` file into a `.dll` but this doesn't seem possible according to the Googling I've done. I can compile a `.py` file into an `.exe` file then pass the text to be parsed as a command line argument. However, I would rather not spawn multiple processes each time I need to parse text.

I was wondering if there were anyway possible to use a Python function in a C++ program or some other means someone can think of. I just want to avoid using C++ to parse text.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: You can build a python interpreter into a c++ program but I'm pretty sure that will be more difficult than parsing your text in c++ to start with. https://docs.python.org/3/extending/embedding.html

Comment: @AlanBirtles Indeed. That documentation page was very vague as to how to go about embedding it. It really only gave examples of code to use **after** it's embedded. Quite the headache I have ahead of me. For the sake of time I may just find a way to use a `.py` executable to parse all my text in the most efficient manner I can find. Thanks.

Comment: see https://docs.python.org/3/faq/windows.html#how-can-i-embed-python-into-a-windows-application

Comment: That leaves you with the (rather tedious) problem of getting the result from Python and having to either convert it (i.e. write a "parser" for Python data structures) or use it directly. I think that writing a parser in C++ may be more difficult, but writing that Python->C++ interface is no walk in the park either *and* it's boring and takes time that you could spend on less boring things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can. You have to embed the python interpreter in your application.

Your calling code would seem something like:

```
Py_Initialize();
PyRun_SimpleString("import parser\n"
                   "parse(" + program_code + ")\n");
```

There is [a whole section in the docs dedicated to embedding Python](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/embedding.html).